# List current object-group local_lan_subnets on Cisco IOS 15.5

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

I'm configuring an Cisco 867VAE and I'm stumped how to list the current (and I assume) dynamic entries in the object group "local_lan_subnets".

The factory settings for the router come with an ACL called "nat-list". The first ACL entry is:

```
10 permit ip object-group local_lan_subnets any
```

I want to make sure this entry is not permitting something it shouldn't. If I take the entry away - all dhcp connected devices lose connection to the outside interface.

I'm trying to run this following command I've seen on a few other posts:

```
sh running-config object-group id local_lan_subnets
```

But it's giving me this error:

> Invalid input detected at '^' marker

I'm quite new to IOS and not sure if this is an ASA command - but I can't work out how to list what is in that object-group. I'm sure it shouldn't be that difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cisco has a paper, [Object Groups for ACLs](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios-xml/ios/sec_data_acl/configuration/15-2mt/sec-object-group-acl.html), which includes a section called, [Example Verifying Object Groups for ACLs](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios-xml/ios/sec_data_acl/configuration/15-2mt/sec-object-group-acl.html#GUID-DB1F87DC-04B0-4A26-AA4F-B354E84A1AC5):

> **Example Verifying Object Groups for ACLs**
>
> The following example shows how to display all object groups:
>
> ```
> Router> enable
> Router# show object-group
> Network object group auth_proxy_acl_deny_dest
>  host 209.165.200.235
> Service object group auth_proxy_acl_deny_services
>  tcp eq www
>  tcp eq 443
> Network object group auth_proxy_acl_permit_dest
>  209.165.200.226 255.255.255.224
>  209.165.200.227 255.255.255.224
>  209.165.200.228 255.255.255.224
>  209.165.200.229 255.255.255.224
>  209.165.200.246 255.255.255.224
>  209.165.200.230 255.255.255.224
>  209.165.200.231 255.255.255.224
>  209.165.200.232 255.255.255.224
>  209.165.200.233 255.255.255.224
>  209.165.200.234 255.255.255.224
> Service object group auth_proxy_acl_permit_services
>  tcp eq www
>  tcp eq 443
> ```
>
> The following example shows how to display information about specific
>   object group-based ACLs:
>
> ```
> Router# show ip access-list my_ogacl_policy
> Extended IP access list my_ogacl_policy
> 10    permit object-group eng_service any any
> ```

Comment: Sorry for the delay - my router crashed and I've only just recovered it via the console. When I run that command - which I had already tried I get the following but it doesn't show the ip address ranges - if this is correct I will mark it answered:    Service object group INTERNAL_UTM_SERVICE

Network object group local_cws_net

Network object group local_lan_subnets
 any

Network object group vpn_remote_subnets
 any